# React Hooks - TypeError: Cannot set property 'isCompleted' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-context

Constantly getting a type error in my todo app. I am trying to set the isComplete property to true.

Error:
`TypeError: Cannot set property 'isCompleted' of undefined`

My complete_todo.js file:

```
import { TodoContext } from './todo_ctx'; 


const MarkComplete = (index) => {
    const [tasks, setTodos] = useContext(TodoContext);

        const newTask = [...tasks];
        newTask[index].isCompleted = true;
        setTodos(newTask);

    return (
        <button onClick={MarkComplete}>Mark Complete</button>
    );
}

export default MarkComplete;
```

My todo_ctx.js file:

```
import React, { useState, createContext} from 'react';

export const TodoContext = createContext();

export const TodoProvider = (props) => { 
    const [tasks, setTodos] = useState([
        {
            id: 1,
            task: 'Learn React',
            description: 'Build a todo app in React',
            isCompleted: false
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            task: 'Learn Node',
            description: 'Build a Node API',
            isCompleted: false
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            task: 'Learn Flutter',
            description: 'Complete Flutter Course',
            isCompleted: false
        }
    ]);

    return (
        <TodoContext.Provider value={[tasks, setTodos]}>
            {props.children}
        </TodoContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I am new to React, Is it something I am missing here??

Answer (score 0):

You have few mistakes in your code.

1. The consumer should be the child of the context provider.
2. Updating state directly in the component body, you should update the state inside a `hook` or a `function`.
3. On button click you are calling the component itself which is wrong.
4. Instead if passing `index` you could pass the task in.

I have made some changes in you code, Please try.

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext, Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

export const TodoContext = createContext();
export const TodoProvider = (props) => {
  const [tasks, setTodos] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      task: 'Learn React',
      description: 'Build a todo app in React',
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      task: 'Learn Node',
      description: 'Build a Node API',
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      task: 'Learn Flutter',
      description: 'Complete Flutter Course',
      isCompleted: false
    }
  ]);
  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={[tasks, setTodos]}>
      <MarkComplete />
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  )
}

const MarkComplete = (props) => {
  const [tasks, setTodos] = useContext(TodoContext);

  function todoHandler(taskId) {
    const newTask = tasks.map(task => {
      if (task.id === taskId) {
        task.isCompleted = !task.isCompleted;
      }
      return task;
    });
    setTodos(newTask);
  }

  return (
    <div >
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Task Id</th>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>isCompleted</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {tasks.map(task => (
            <tr key={task.id}>
              <td>{task.id}</td>
              <td>{task.task}</td>
              <td>{String(task.isCompleted)}</td>
              <td><button onClick={() => todoHandler(task.id)}>Mark Complete ({task.id})</button></td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>

  );
}




function App() {

  return <TodoProvider />
}
export default App;
```

**Codesandbox Link:**

[image: Edit nervous-tdd-y2y43]

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrapped your App using your provider???

Example:

```html
import { TodoProvider } from "./src/context/todo_ctx.js";

const App = createAppContainer(navigator);
export default () => {
  return (
    <TodoProvider>
      <App />
    </TodoProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So I don't think you need a context there, especially the way you are using it. I tried this for you, lemme know if this helps:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Todos = () => {
  const [tasks, setTodos] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      task: "Learn React",
      description: "Build a todo app in React",
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      task: "Learn Node",
      description: "Build a Node API",
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      task: "Learn Flutter",
      description: "Complete Flutter Course",
      isCompleted: false
    }
  ]);

  const setTodoHelper = taskId => {
    setTodos(
      tasks.map(x =>
        x.id === taskId ? { ...x, isCompleted: !x.isCompleted } : x
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      {tasks.map(task => (
        <Todo key={task.id} {...task} setTodoHelper={setTodoHelper} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const Todo = ({ id, setTodoHelper, isCompleted }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{id}</div>
      <div>completed: {String(isCompleted)} </div>
      <button onClick={() => setTodoHelper(id)}>Mark Complete</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Todos;
```

ref: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-pond-x96sy